# How can i extract folding information of html using rvest package?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I try to do web scraping from this website [[link]](https://carro.mercadolibre.com.co/MCO-611624087-chevrolet-camaro-2017-62-ss-_JM#position=16&type=item&tracking_id=f0c0ddc3-84a0-46ce-8545-5df59fe50a63).

In this part, I find a piece of folding hidden information.

[Hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnfHT.png)

I try this:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://carro.mercadolibre.com.co/MCO-611624087-chevrolet-camaro-2017-62-ss-_JM#position=16&type=item&tracking_id=f0c0ddc3-84a0-46ce-8545-5df59fe50a63"

session(url) %>% 
  html_node(xpath='//*[@id="root-app"]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]') %>%
html_text2()
```

But, the code doesn't catch all information:

```
[1] "Frenos ABS: Sí\n\nAirbag para conductor y pasajero: Sí\n\nPotencia: 455 hp"
```

If I click on folding information, it's shown:

[Show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chxlA.png)

Another way to extract the information, is using div class "ui-pdp-specs-groups":

```
session(url) %>% 
  html_node(".ui-pdp-specs-groups-collapsable.ui-pdp-specs") %>%
  html_text2()

[1] "Items del vehículo\n\nFrenos ABS: Sí\n\nAirbag para conductor y pasajero: Sí\n\nPotencia: 455 hp\n\nVer más características"
```

How can I extract the missing information from the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pulled from a script tag dynamically. You can use regex on the page source as string (not parsing as html) to pull out the the relevant info.

In this case the pattern used returns all the technical specifications plus some other page info. I parse into json object with jsonlite then extract the technical specifications and finally print the section containing the data you want.

There is a little work left to do to just parse out the values,  as shown on screen, from the page placement instructions that are carried alongside the values, for when the page on the website renders:

---

**R:**

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

page <- read_html('https://carro.mercadolibre.com.co/MCO-611624087-chevrolet-camaro-2017-62-ss-_JM#position=16&type=item&tracking_id=f0c0ddc3-84a0-46ce-8545-5df59fe50a63') %>% toString()
res <- page %>% stringr::str_match("window\\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = (.*?);\n") %>% .[2]
data <- jsonlite::parse_json(res)
technical_spec <- data$initialState$components$technical_specifications
all_specs <- technical_spec$specs
print(all_specs[3])
```

---

**Regex:**

[image]

Comment: Awesome, it works perfectly! Thank you very much. With the `all_specs` list, I can extract all information with regular expression easily.